# Diferencia entre elementos de un ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

Les comento que tengo un **ArrayList** de la siguiente forma:

```
Dim matriz As New ArrayList


matriz.Add(5)
matriz.Add(2)
matriz.Add(4)

matriz.Sort
```

Ahora lo que requiero es saber cual es la diferencia entre elementos; es decir

```
Elemento1 = 5
Elemento2 = 2 
Elemento3 = 4
```

Quiero saber si existe alguna forma o una propiedad del `Array` que me ayude a lograr esto:

**Pseudocódigo**

```
Diferencia1 = ValorAbsoluto(Elemento1 - Elemento2)
Diferencia2 = ValorAbsoluto(Elemento1 - Elemento3)
Diferencia3 = ValorAbsoluto(Elemento2 - Elemento3)
```

Comment: Que tal  @M. Gress, a que te refieres con la diferencia o  cómo quieres relacionar los elementos?

Comment: Hola @JulioMorenoDev quiero obtener la diferencia entre todos los elementos es decir 5-2=3 , 5-4 = 1, 2-4 = 2 (Valor absoluto)